# PowerShell Query SQL IF Column = 0

Tags: sql, powershell

I'm a bit out of my wheelhouse on this one, but what I'm trying to do is a have a web form gather all our new user information, dump it in a table then use those columns to populate the data for my PowerShell user provisioning scripts.

The part I'm struggling with is querying the data and getting it into variables in PowerShell. Assume a table with basic GivenName,SurName,Title etc. columns. I want to pull all rows of data (new users) that the "Created" column equals 0, and put each column into a variable to use. At the end of the user creation script, I will update the "Created" column to 1 to avoid the user being re-created next batch run but the row will remain.

Any tips on the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

So we do this alot, so much that we created a function we always leverage for taking data in or out of SQL.

```
function Get-SQL ($query,$server,$database, $username, $password) {
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('username') -eq $true -and $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('password') -eq $true) {
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $server; Database = $database; User ID=$username; Password=$password;"
} else {
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $server; Database = $database; Integrated Security = True"
}

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $query
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd

$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) | Out-Null
$SqlConnection.Close()

return $DataSet.Tables[0]
}
```

Now dont get scared of all that craziness, just put it at the top of your script (we actually have it in a global functional library we call on all of our automation scripts but putting it inline will be fine)

Once that function is there you can simply do this:

```
$MyData = get-sql -server "MyServer" -database "MyDatabaseName" -Query "select * from myTable where created = 0"
```

Then you will be able to access the all columns via the $MyData object. But in reality you will want to do a foreach loop to really work with each record.

```
foreach ($whatever in $myData) {
write-output "Now working on record: $($whatever.GivenName) $($whatever.SurName)"  
# Do more stuff you want

#now Update SQL
get-sql -server "MyServer" -database "MyDatabaseName" -Query "update myTable set created = 1 where UniqueUserID = '$($whatever.UniqueUserID)'"
}
```

Last things to note, you need a unique User ID. This can be anything, here we always use objectGUID from Active Directory but if you dont have that then setup UserID field in the db, and have it auto increment an int. You always want a immutableID (meaning something that will never change like a name or an email will). Also notice when using vars in a string I always use $($var) syntax, works when your strings are in double quotes and can help avoid issues.

This should be enough to get you going... good luck!

Comment: That is perfect. Nice and clean and easy to comprehend. Much appreciated.